# How to Read SharePoint Online list data from an external HTML page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, html

I have a requirement to read list data from SharePoint Online and display on an external html page.

Most of articles points towards REST API calls But how I can make an authenticated REST API call from an external HTML page?

Please, anyone can help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Check the solution below:

[SharePoint Online Authentication via JavaScript](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SharePoint-Online-d9fdb136#content)

Or try to use [Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) for JavaScript](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks. I tried with first option and getting error on browser - "XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80700013, Could not complete the operation due to error 80700013" and "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf' from origin 'http://localhost:55955' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: Do I have to add anything specific to my calling HTML page ?

Comment: As a workaround, we can also create a custom web api or REST API with CSOM C# code to get list data in the local domain server, then consume the API in the local HTML page.